# Using same term for slug and category

Tags: categories, terms, slug

I am having problems with a site that uses the category “vacatures” for posts. The “Vacatures” page, lists those posts.

Some time ago the client has made a page called “vacatures” and replaced the old “vacatures” posts page with his new “vacatures” page (a page) His “vacatures” page is the main-page, and has children (sub-pages) like vacatures-bouw, vacatures-civiel etc.

Now we want the old page back, so the posts page with the “vacatures” posts. I changed the menu, so that it again links to /category/vacatures/
But if you click the menu, the site tries to go to the old “vacatures” page (the page). I deleted that page, but now, on clicking the link, you end up on vacatures-bouw, a sub-page of the old vacatuers page.

If I type https://mysite/category/vacatures/ in the address bar, I get a “page not found error”
If I go in the dashboard, and go to Posts>Categories >Vacatures> View I go to the vacatures-bouw page.

I understand that in WP, you cannot use the same term for a category and a page/slug. Makes sense. But it has already been done, now I need to fix this and get this working again. Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, found it. it *is* possible to have the same slug for a page and a category name. The problem was that someone installed a "redirection" plugin that caused the problems.

Lesson learned is to restrict the capabilities of people working on the website, so that they cannot install plugins..